# How to get the correct value?

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to allow user to input the key that they are looking for and then print out the corresponding key and values. However, if I use the following code, it prints out the correct key but wrong value

Example of text file :
apple (key)

sweet

red in colour

small

Grape (key)

purple

comes in different colour

small

juicy

```py
name = (input("Type fruit name : "))
f = open(myfile, 'r+')
for key in f:
    if name in key:
        print({key:value})
```

Comment: Where is `value` supposed to come from?  It's not defined anywhere in the code you posted.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand what you try to achieve. Could you please paste the user input, the txt.file and the expected outcome.